# How to use String methods in JSP function?

Tags: java, string, jsp, user-interface

I have a Java code and now I want to convert it into JSP. But I am facing problems and don't know how to use String methods in JSP function.

I have a below Java code:

```
public void rapidToStandard() { 
    boolean flag = false;
    enteredPath = tbProjectName.getText();

    final char[] chars=enteredPath.toCharArray();

    for(int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
       if(chars[i] == '\\') {                   
          flag = true ;
       } else {
          tbProjectName.requestFocus();                     
       }
    }           

    if(flag == true) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please enter single forward(/) slash",
            "Error",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        tbProjectName.requestFocus();
    } else if (tbProjectName.getText().equals("C:/Utility")) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please enter another folder name", 
            "Error" , JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        tbProjectName.requestFocus();
    }                                                                       
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Write this in scriplet. Please clear your question about what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: You say in a function but you gave no function definition.

Answer (score 0):

String is inside the java.lang package.
java.lang is implicity imported for every java class.
If you need other packages you can import in jsp like below

```
<%@ page import="java.sql.*,java.util.List,java.util.ArrayList,DBPool" %>
```